# iOS 11 Large Navigation Bar title Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios11

How do I make the navigation bar title the new large version in iOS 11 using objective C?

There are lots of examples in swift but none for objective c.

Apple suggests

```
 @property(nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL prefersLargeTitles;
```

But that is not working.

My code is

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UINavigationBar appearance] backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The property exists; that's just a fact. It's not "working" because you didn't *do* anything. You can't just sit there and stare at it. If you want this property to be YES, you must *set* it to YES:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Hello"
    navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
        ]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

For more and detail: http://iosrevisited.blogspot.in/2017/09/navigation-bar-with-large-titles-and.html